# How to say the following in German and "habe" or "hatte"?

Tags: english-to-german

Original:

> I didn't see her and when I realized it was her, it was already too late.

Übersetzung:

> Ich hatte sie nicht gesehen, und when ich hatte realized es war sie, es war schon zu spat.
>   Ich hatte sie nicht gesehen, und when ich habe realized es war sie, es war schon zu spat.

*Habe* oder *hatte* - welches und warum?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

First of all, we should keep in mind that präteritum is normally not used in spoken german.

Having said that, let´s break it into pieces.

1) "I didn't see her".

Teoretically, ***Perfekt Partizip*** should suffice here, but there is a fact that we must take into account, ***something*** happens (***happened***) ***after*** the subject (***I***) ***"didn´t see her"***, so we should use another form of past that lets us describe an event in the past and another event that came short after, that is ***Plusquamperfekt***, which is built with the verb in ***Partizip II*** and "***haben***" or "***sein***" (depending on how the verb builds its Perfekt) in ***Präteritum***.

Our posibilities would then be:

- ich sah sie nicht. (Präteritum)
- ich habe sie nicht gesehen. (Perfekt)
- ich ***hatte*** sie nicht ***gesehen.*** ( Plusquamperfekt, chosen )

2) "and when I realized it was her" ***or*** "and when i realized ***that*** it was her".

Now we should talk about the event that came after what we just formulated in "far" past, but we talk about it in "near" past ( Perfekt Partizip ).

- und als ich ***bemerkt habe***, (Perfekt)

Now for the "that it was her" part, we try first to use Perfekt Partizip, but since the main verb is "sein", and "sein" is a modal verb, we use Präteritum instead of Perfekt.

- ***dass*** es sie war. (Präteritum)

3) "it was already too late"

We use Präteritum once again, since a ***Modales Verb*** is involved.

- es war schon zu spät.

In my opinion this would be a good aproximation to your idea:
***Ich hatte sie nicht gesehen, und als ich bemerkt habe, dass sie es war, war es schon zu spät.***

I would personally say it this way:
***Nachdem ich sie nicht gesehen hatte, habe ich bemerkt, dass es sich um sie handelte, aber es war schon zu spät***

---

***Improvement*** by @Unknown User included.

---

***Improvement*** by @Eugene Seidel:

***Ich hatte sie nicht gesehen, und als ich sie erkannt habe, war es schon zu spät.***

***Reason***: Odd / Non-standard use of "Nachdem".

Comment: +1 for using three tenses in one sentence and for the reasoned explanation. As bizarre as it sounds, German really does work like this.

Comment: OMG, that was superb, lol. Gute gemacht :)

Comment: But "und als ich bemerkt habe" could we say, wenn or wann instead of als?

Comment: Statt `dass es sie war` würde ich `dass sie es war` vorschlagen, eher noch `... und als ich bemerkte, sie ist es, ...`. Der letzte Satz ist m.E. misslungen. Und das nach der schönen Erklärung!

Comment: @Knoretae You can improve your first suggestion like so: `Ich hatte sie nicht gesehen, und als ich sie erkannt habe, war es schon zu spät.` (**erkannt** is past participle of the verb **erkennen**.) Your second suggestion may not be optimal -- it sounds odd due to non-standard use of "nachdem" -- but again, nice handling of tenses there.

Comment: @NomanArain & Knoretae it is not possible to interchange "als" with "wenn/wann" in this case. "wenn" usually describes a 'case' and "wann" is the question for a moment of time: e.g.: "Wann hast du sie gesehen? - Gerade eben." the english 'when' is in this case interchangeable with 'as' and thus cannot be translated as "wann", which is 'when' and only 'when'. 'when' would be more appropriately translated with an if-clause

Comment: As a native I have to say that every version with "erkannt habe" sounds incredibly wrong to me. I can't explain it right now but I'd be very very skeptical about this.And the version you favor (@Knoretae) is nothing anyone I know would ever say or write.

Comment: here is a link to weakly back my point:  http://www.google.de/search?client=opera&q=%22er+sah+sie+nicht,+und+als+er+ihn+bemerkte,+war+es+zu+sp%C3%A4t%22&sourceid=opera&ie=utf-8&oe=utf-8&channel=suggest#hl=de&client=opera&hs=27Z&channel=suggest&sclient=psy-ab&q=%22und+als+er+sie+bemerkte%2C+war+es+zu+sp%C3%A4t%22&oq=%22und+als+er+sie+bemerkte%2C+war+es+zu+sp%C3%A4t%22&gs_l=serp.3...3942.4160.2.4708.3.3.0.0.0.2.243.560.0j2j1.3.0...0.0...1c.1.5.psy-ab.p1B_Nc48vi0&pbx=1&bav=on.2,or.r_gc.r_pw.r_qf.&bvm=bv.43148975,d.bGE&fp=a7e4f01e37b4ab9f&biw=1333&bih=660

Answer (score 3):

Ich habe sie erst nicht gesehen und als ich sie dann erkannt habe, war es zu spät.

Answer (score 1):

> Ich hatte sie zunächst nicht gesehen, und als mir dann klar wurde, dass sie es war, war es schon zu spät.
>
> Ich sah sie nicht, und als ich dann erkannt, dass sie es war, war es schon zu spät.

That would be for a novel or a short story. The second version is the more literal one. As for a spoken version I'd suggest this:

> Ich hab' sie nicht gesehen, und dann, als ich gemerkt hab', dass sie es ist, war es schon zu spät.

Answer (score 0):

> Ich sah sie nicht und als ich erkannte (merkte) dass sie es war, war
>   es schon zu spät.

Comment: sorry, I edited your answer and I actually wanted to edit mine... I'll try to reverse it.